# Method logging in Python

Tags: python, logging

I'd like something equivalent to

```
calling method: $METHOD_NAME
args:           $ARGS
output:         $OUTPUT
```

to be automatically logged to a file (via the `logging` module, possibly) for every (user-defined) method call. The best solution I can come up with is to write a decorator that will do this, and then add it to every function. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at the [trace](http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html) module in the standard library, which

> allows you to trace program execution, generate annotated statement coverage listings, print caller/callee relationships and list functions executed during a program run. It can be used in another program or from the command line.

You can also log to disk:

```
import sys
import trace

# create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to
# do tracing or line-counting or both.
tracer = trace.Trace(
    ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
    trace=0,
    count=1)

# run the new command using the given tracer
tracer.run('main()')

# make a report, placing output in /tmp
r = tracer.results()
r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir="/tmp")
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach that might simplify things a bit would be to use a metaclass to automatically apply your decorator for you. It'd cut down on the typing at the expense of requiring you to delve into the arcane and mysterious world of metaclass programming.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how exactly are you going to use it.
Most generic approach would be to follow stdlib's 'profile' module path and therefore have control over each call, but its somewhat slow.

If you know which modules you need to track before giving them control, I'd go with iterating over all their members and wrapping with tracking decorator. This way tracked code stays clean and it doesn't take too much coding to implement.

Answer (score 1):

A decorator would be a simple approach for a smaller project, however with decorators you have to be careful about passing arguments to make sure that they don't get mangled on their way through.  A metaclass would probably be more of the "right" way to do it without having to worry about adding decorators to every new method.